# Getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain

I am having difficulty finding the error for defining data in my code, when I condense it. I wrote 4 tests for my code and 3 have passed. I am getting a error on test 3.

Adding this solves the issue but I am trying to keep it condensed.

```
blockchain.addBlock({data: 'Bears'});

blockchain.addBlock({data: 'Beets'});

blockchain.addBlock({data: 'Battlestar Galatica'});
```

This is currently what I have when receiving the error.

```
describe('and the chain contains a block with an invalid field',()=>{
    it('returns false', () => {

        blockchain.chain[2].data = 'some-bad-and-evil-data';

        expect(Blockchain.isValidChain(blockchain.chain)).toBe(false);
        });
    });
```

```
FAIL ./blockchain.test.js
  ● Blockchain › isValidChain() › and the chain contains a block with an invalid field › returns false

    TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

      54 |     it('returns false', () => {
      55 |
    > 56 |         blockchain.chain[2].data = 'some-bad-and-evil-data';
         |         ^
      57 |
      58 |         expect(Blockchain.isValidChain(blockchain.chain)).toBe(false);
      59 |         });

      at Object.it (blockchain.test.js:56:9)
```

Comment: `blockchain.chain` has elements < 3 that's why it is throwing the error. Print the `blockchain.chain` to check how many elements are there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no element at index 2 of `blockchain.chain`. In general, it is the most likely reason for getting this error while trying to access a field of an element in an array.

In another word;

```
someCollection[index].someField
```

If you see an error containing `Undefined`, `NullReference`, `NullPointer` keywords then your collection does not have `index + 1` many elements.

Comment: I tried using                                   beforeEach(() => {
    blockchain.addBlock({data: 'Bears'});
    blockchain.addBlock({data: 'Beets'});
    blockchain.addBlock({data: 'Battlestar Galatica'});
    });

Comment: @EnricoShippole You use **addBlock** but you try to get **chain**. Adding 3 block does not guarantee having 3 chains.

Comment: This is what i did to try to validate the chains. I'm unsure how to format responses correctly as this is my first time posting on stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I've read the code, but I couldn't find a relevant information. Validity of chains has nothing to do with their number. You see, **blockchain.chain[2]** is Undefined (null). You need to find a way to make sure there are 3 elements in **blockchain.chain**

Comment: I would suggest you not to put code in comment section=) You may find refreshing your memory on arrays helpful. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Ok. I appreciate all the help. Definitely helped a lot. Ill delete my previous comment. I think I may have found something which was throwing off the array I created. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯